# Creating text file from list in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a list in the following format with `ID`, `X` and `Y` coordinates:

```
[[1.0, 300617.25483065785, 9761077.375684619],
 [1.0, 301117.25483065785, 9760577.375684619],
 [1.0, 301117.25483065785, 9760077.375684619],
 [1.0, 314117.25483065785, 9745577.375684619],
 [2.0, 297617.25483065785, 9745077.375684619],
 [2.0, 298117.25483065785, 9745077.375684619],
 [1.0, 314617.25483065785, 9745077.375684619],
 [1.0, 315117.25483065785, 9745077.375684619],
 [2.0, 298617.25483065785, 9744577.375684619],
 [2.0, 299117.25483065785, 9744577.375684619]]
```

Now I would like to write this list in the text file in the following format:

```
1
X_Coordinate      Y_Coordinate
............      ............
X_Coordinate      Y_Coordinate
END

2
X_Coordinate       Y_Coordinate
............       ............
X_Coordinate       Y_coordinate    
END
END
```

How could I implement this in python? I have tried like this:

```
new_arry = numpy.array(x)
textfile = os.path.join(path, 'test123.txt')
outFile = open(textfile, 'w')

for i in grid_code:
   new_list=numpy.where(new_arry[:,0]==i)
   mask_list=new_arry[new_list,:]
```

Here `x` is my list. Now I would like to write each masked array into a file with X and Y coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? People at Stackoverflow will not write a program for you. Try something, once you get really stuck, ask here for help.

Comment: Update your question; don't put that whole bunch of code in a comment (looks incomprehensible). There's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26336470/edit) link for your question.

Comment: You're comparing a float to an int (`numpy.where(new_arry[:,0]==i)`); that rarely ends well.

Comment: Use `print` statements liberally around your code, to debug your problem and understand what's going on. Or, if you like, use the [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) debugger (bit more difficult than `print` statements though!). There is much more you can do to find out what's going wrong before you get really stuck!

Comment: You haven't actually  *tried* writing your results to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what grid_code was, but a better way to figure out what all of the ids are would be to use `numpy.unique(new_array[:,0])` which will give you a list of the unique values in the first column. This will ensure you aren't trying to compare floats to ints for instance.

It is better practice to use `with` when you're working with files, because that way you can be sure they will get closed when you're done, rather than having to remember to `.close()` them.

In your `numpy.where` statement, the way its written `mask_list` will be `[ [ [], [], ..., [] ] ]`, i.e. will have an extra set of brackets. You can get around this by defining `mask_array = new_array[new_list[0],:]`

Since you want a custom format, you will could define it using a loop.

```
with open(os.path.join(path, 'test123.txt'), 'w') as outFile:
    for i in numpy.unique(new_array[:,0]):
        new_list = numpy.where(new_array[:,0] == i)
        mask_list = new_array[new_list[0],:]
        outFile.write(str(i)+'\n')
        for line in mask_list:
            outFile.write('\t'.join((str(line[1]),str(line[2]))) + '\n')
        outFile.write('END\n')
    outFile.write('END\n')
```